# TSQL - Calculate time between punches but exclude break time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Not sure if this is a unique question or not.

I'm needing to get calculated punch in and punch out times for a labor tracking system. Our crew has breaks from 10-10:20 AM and from 1-1:20 PM.

What I need to figure out is how to subtract this time from a total if they are still punched in during these breaks.

For example, if Joe punches in to a job at 09:53 and punches out at 10:23, I want it to show    10 minutes instead of 30.

How could I do this for few "blackout" times of 10-10:20, 1-1:20, 11-11:20, and 5-5:20?

Comment: This looks too strict. What happen if worker need to do some work during the break time? Will tell the boss wait 20 minutes?

Comment: I agree it is strict but what management wants, management gets :)

Comment: can a punch in-out overlap with multiple blackout?

Comment: That is very possible

Comment: OK, I will charge extra for that, let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

This return the total of work minutes. This check if the worker time overlap with each break time and then change it to indicate how much overlap was.

Then calculate the total of minutes in break and finally subtract for the total of time worker punch in_out.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/QUZIQ7966)**

```
WITH time_off as (
    SELECT * ,
           CASE WHEN w.in_w < b.out_b AND w.out_w > b.in_b
                THEN 'overlap' 
           END as overlap,
           CASE WHEN w.in_w < b.in_b 
                THEN b.in_b
                ELSE w.in_w
           END as break_start,
           CASE WHEN w.out_w > b.out_b 
                THEN b.out_b
                ELSE w.out_w
           END as break_end       
    FROM workers w
    CROSS JOIN breaks b
), break_total as (
    SELECT worker_id, in_w, out_w, SUM (CASE WHEN overlap = 'overlap'
                                             THEN datediff(minute, break_start,break_end)
                                             ELSE 0
                                        END) as break_total
    FROM time_off
    GROUP BY worker_id, in_w, out_w
)
SELECT worker_id,
       datediff(minute, in_w, out_w) - break_total as total_minutes
FROM  break_total
```

For some debug do:

```
SELECT * FROM time_off;
SELECT * FROM break_total;
```