# Time elapsed between two dates (In a specific time range) ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I am creating a query that shows me the time elapsed between two dates, only taking into account only the one that is Monday through Friday from 08:00 to 17:00, for example:

For example, if a petition opens on day 1 at 6:30 p.m. and closes on day 2 at 8:45 p.m., the TMO is 45 minutes.
If it closes on day 3 at 8:45, the TMO is 9 hours and 45 minutes.

Example 2:
If a petition opens on Friday at 16:45 and closes on Tuesday at 8:30, the MTO would be: 15 minutes on Friday, nine hours on Monday and 30 minutes on Tuesday for an MTO = 9 hours 45 minutes

The query is performed on a single column of type date as I show below

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I currently use a LAG function to make the query, but I can not create something functional, not even optimal to incorporate, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What are the two dates?  I see one date . . . or a column with many dates.

Comment: And why would LAG have anything to do with your problem? Is each date_time the closing of one petition and the opening of another one?

Comment: The first date is the previous row and the second date is the row on which it is located

Comment: That is, a single column is used

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Are you OK with the LAG function? It is easier to explain the answer to your question without mixing it with LAG. (Then you can use the answer WITH LAG to solve your actual problem).

Comment: How we know what time the petition open and close? Do you have a query? What are those date times?

Comment: I provide an answer to a similar problem [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939626/tsql-calculate-time-between-punches-but-exclude-break-time/46940382#46940382) In that case the OP didnt want to count breaks and provide breaks time ranges. In your case you have to provide working time ranges and check for overlaps.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - the problem you linked to is not similar. In the problem here, you need to know how many work hours are, for example, from this Wednesday at 11:30 am until next Monday at 1 pm. Add only the work hours from Wednesday (partial), Thursday and Friday (9 hours each), skip Saturday and Sunday, and add yours from Monday (partial). And work hours start at 8 am and end at 5 pm.

Comment: @mathguy Is exactly as this problem. If you have working ranges like `2017/11/02 08:00:00 - 2017/11/02 17:00:00` is easy check how much your wider range overlap with each working day. And also allow you work with holidays.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - in that problem you had explicit punch-in and punch-out times from which to do the computations. You could reduce this problem to that one (which already means they are not "exactly" the same) but that would be a lot of extra work. Rather than argue about it, though, please adapt your solution to the problem in this thread, test it, and compare it to what I posted. Cheers!

Comment: @mathguy `You could reduce this problem`  mean the problems are the same. I will adapt my solution if OP provide more information. By now would only be a guess and I hate waste my time with bad guesses.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The OP has already explained the problem in full. He did not provide testable inputs, but the "start" and "end" date-times are in consecutive rows of the table, he said so in the problem statement and again in one of the comments. Here is the problem: given any two date_times, how many WORK hours are between them? Work hours are 8:00 to 17:00 on work days only (not on weekends). This is self-contained now.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I have answered late for problems with my internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution below I will ignore the "lag" part of your problem, which you said you know how to use. I am only showing how to count "working hours" between any two date_times (they may be during or before or after work hours, and/or they can be on weekend days; the computation is the same in all cases).

Explaining the answer in words: For two given date-times, "start" and "end", calculate how many "work" hours elapsed from the beginning of the week (from Monday 00:00:00) till each of them. This is in fact a calculation for ONE date, not for TWO dates. Then: given "start" and "end", calculate this number of hours for each of them; subtract the "end" number of hours from the "start" number of hours. To the result, add x times 5 times 9, where x is the difference in weeks between Monday 00:00:00 of the two dates. (If they are in the same week, the difference will be 0.)

To truncate a date to the beginning of the day, we use `TRUNC(dt)`. To truncate to the beginning of Monday, `TRUNC(dt, 'iw')`.

To compute how many "work" hours are from the beginning of the date `dt` until the actual time-of-day we can use the calculation

```
greatest(0, least(17/24, dt - trunc(dt)) - 8/24)
```

(the results will be in days; we calculate everything in days and then we can convert to hours). However, in the final formula we must check to see if the date is a Saturday or Sunday, in which case this should just be zero. Or, better, we can adjust the calculation a bit later, when we count from the beginning of Monday (we can use `least( 5*9/24, ...)`).

Putting everything together:

```
with
  inputs ( dt1, dt2 ) as (
    select to_date('2017-09-25 11:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
           to_date('2017-10-01 22:45:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    from   dual
  )
-- End of SIMULATED input dates (for testing only).
select 24 *
     ( least(5 * (17 - 8) / 24, greatest(0, least(17/24, dt2 - trunc(dt2)) - 8/24)
                                + (17 - 8) / 24 * (trunc(dt2) - trunc(dt2, 'iw'))) 
       -
       least(5 * (17 - 8) / 24, greatest(0, least(17/24, dt1 - trunc(dt1)) - 8/24)
                                + (17 - 8) / 24 * (trunc(dt1) - trunc(dt1, 'iw'))) 
       + 5 * (17 - 8) / 24 * (trunc(dt2, 'iw') - trunc(dt1, 'iw')) / 7
     )
       as duration_in_hours
from   inputs
;


DURATION_IN_HOURS
-----------------
           41.500
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect, what remains for me to incorporate it is minimal, really thanks

Comment: Please make sure to test it with a variety of inputs though; since you didn't provide inputs in usable form (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, or a WITH clause), I did very little testing myself. I can guarantee that the approach is correct, but I already fixed a mistake in my computations (for full days since the beginning of the week, I forgot to multiply by 9/24 when I first posted the answer - and it just happened to have no ill effect on the single test case I built, because the start and end were the same day of the week!)

Comment: I had a group of scenarios prepared because I had been with this for a while, I have tried them all and the result has been the expected, thank you very much @mathguy